# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null, while running selenium test on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am running selenium test on Jenkins and using maven and TestNG for test cases. My test cases are running fine on my local machine IntelliJ and via terminal. However, when running it through my local Jenkins job i am getting this error.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

My Config:

OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04,
Jenkins: 2.332.3,
Java: 11

Jenkins Job Config:

job: maven job,
root POM: /pom.xml,
Goals and option: test,

Chromedriver: 101.0.4951.41

```
-------------------------------------------------------
```

### T E S T S

```
Running TestSuite
[main] WARN org.testng.internal.Configuration - Detected a static method [general.BaseTest.afterMethod()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
[main] WARN org.testng.internal.Configuration - Detected a static method [general.BaseTest.beforeTest()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
[main] WARN org.testng.internal.Configuration - Detected a static method [general.BaseTest.afterTest()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
[main] WARN org.testng.internal.Configuration - Detected a static method [general.BaseTest.beforeMethod()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
before test
Before Method executing
/home/vend-sarosh/Documents/Web/Selenium/driver/chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323b3ec10d056025ab95c23a31997c9-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#904}) on port 58950
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 61.4 sec <<< FAILURE!
beforeMethod(TestCases.login)  Time elapsed: 61.28 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at config.browserFactory.BrowserDriver.browser(BrowserDriver.java:47)
    at config.browserFactory.BrowserDriver.webDriver(BrowserDriver.java:26)
    at general.functions.<clinit>(functions.java:36)
    at general.BaseTest.beforeMethod(BaseTest.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:65)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:381)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:319)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:803)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:589)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)

afterMethod(TestCases.login)  Time elapsed: 0.037 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class general.functions
    at general.BaseTest.afterMethod(BaseTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:65)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:381)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  login>BaseTest.beforeMethod:34 » ExceptionInInitializer
  login>BaseTest.afterMethod:55 » NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class gen...

Tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/vend-sarosh/Documents/Web/Selenium/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions:

1. In my case Jenkins uses Java version 11 (Jenkins 2.363) the problem disappeared when I switched the Java version on my Build-Server from 17 to 11
2. My project was using Guice 3. After switching to Guice 5 the problem also disappeared